# CastCompanionLibrary : mApiClient or mRemoteMediaPlayer is null

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm facing a problem trying to implement Chromecast on my application with CastCompanionLibrary.

Here is how I initialise my CastManager.

```
public static VideoCastManager mCastMgr;
//chromeCast init
public static VideoCastManager getVideoCastManager(Context ctx) {

    if (mCastMgr == null) {
        mCastMgr = VideoCastManager.initialize(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.CAST_APPLICATION_ID), null, null); 
        mCastMgr.enableFeatures(VideoCastManager.FEATURE_NOTIFICATION | VideoCastManager.FEATURE_LOCKSCREEN |
                VideoCastManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RECONNECT 
                | VideoCastManager.FEATURE_NOTIFICATION |
                VideoCastManager.FEATURE_DEBUGGING);
    }
    mCastMgr.setContext(ctx);
    return mCastMgr;
}
```

Here is just a test code to display one media. This method is called in the onCreate.

```
private     MediaRouteButton    mMediaRouteButton;  
private     VideoCastManager    mVideoCastManager;
private     VideoCastConsumerImpl mVideoCastConsumer;

private void setupChromeCast() {
    mVideoCastManager = MyApplication.getVideoCastManager(this);
    mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    mVideoCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(mMediaRouteButton);

    mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mVideoCastConsumer = new VideoCastConsumerImpl() {
        //          .....
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onCastAvailabilityChanged(boolean castPresent) {
            super.onCastAvailabilityChanged(castPresent);
            mMediaRouteButton.setVisibility(castPresent ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationConnected(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata,
                String sessionId, boolean wasLaunched) {
            Bundle mediaInfo = new Bundle();
            mediaInfo.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "toto");
            mediaInfo.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "le roro");
            mediaInfo.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, "mdr");
            mediaInfo.putString("movie-urls", "https://ia902302.us.archive.org/27/items/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4/video_test.mp4");
            mediaInfo.putString("content-type", "video/mp4");
            ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
            images.add("https://scontent-a-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10426650_10203984861039843_6191993092115493723_n.jpg?oh=8cb095f97c4b8f7d726d4a4d418d65fc&oe=54C484F9");
            images.add("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Toto'025.jpg");
            mediaInfo.putStringArrayList("images", images);
            MediaInfo mSelectedMedia = com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.utils.Utils.toMediaInfo(mediaInfo);
            try {
                mVideoCastManager.startCastControllerActivity(getApplicationContext(), mSelectedMedia, 0, true);
                finish();
                return ;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
}
```

And then in the onResume I assign my VideoCastConsumer to my Manager.

```
// CHROMECAST
    mVideoCastManager.addVideoCastConsumer(mVideoCastConsumer);
```

I have no problem with the Chromecast detection it's working great. I select my device with the app and then it displays my Application name on my screen and do nothing. The reason must be in this debug message.

```
09-30 17:36:26.164: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(7630): [v1.10] Route added: Chambre
09-30 17:36:34.997: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] Successfully added the new BaseCastConsumer listener com.MYAPP.AndroidApp.PlayerActivity$12@420459e0
09-30 17:36:34.997: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] Successfully added the new CastConsumer listener com.MYAPP.AndroidApp.PlayerActivity$12@420459e0
09-30 17:36:38.576: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(7630): [v1.10] onRouteSelected: info=MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:92ec2ab63d7e51ff96603bf08487fbc6, name=Chambre, description=Chromecast, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0, volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=580], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }
09-30 17:36:38.578: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] acquiring a connection to Google Play services for "Chambre" (92ec2ab63d7e51ff96603bf08487fbc6)
09-30 17:36:38.590: D/ccl_CastMediaRouterCal(7630): [v1.10] onResult: mSelectedDevice=Chambre
09-30 17:36:39.593: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onConnected() reached with prior suspension: false
09-30 17:36:39.598: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] launchApp() is called
09-30 17:36:39.598: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] Launching app
09-30 17:36:39.640: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onVolumeChanged() reached
09-30 17:36:39.641: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: 
09-30 17:36:39.757: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: null
09-30 17:36:40.988: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] launchApplication() -> success result
09-30 17:36:40.988: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onApplicationConnected() reached with sessionId: A5E3356F-14BD-FD02-6044-8911E8E4D215, and mReconnectionStatus=INACTIVE
09-30 17:36:40.989: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] startNotificationService()
09-30 17:36:40.994: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] attachMedia()
09-30 17:36:40.996: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] Registering MediaChannel namespace
09-30 17:36:41.007: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onApplicationStatusChanged() reached: Ready To Cast
09-30 17:36:41.008: D/ccl_VideoCastNotificat(7630): [v1.10] onCreate()
09-30 17:36:41.009: D/ccl_BaseCastManager(7630): [v1.10] Successfully added the new BaseCastConsumer listener com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$1@41f7edb0
09-30 17:36:41.009: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] Successfully added the new CastConsumer listener com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.notification.VideoCastNotificationService$1@41f7edb0
09-30 17:36:41.009: D/ccl_VideoCastNotificat(7630): [v1.10] onStartCommand
09-30 17:36:41.010: D/ccl_VideoCastNotificat(7630): [v1.10] onStartCommand(): Action: ACTION_VISIBILITY true
09-30 17:36:41.684: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] RemoteMediaPlayer::onStatusUpdated() is reached
09-30 17:36:41.684: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onRemoteMediaPlayerStatusUpdated() reached
09-30 17:36:41.684: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] mApiClient or mRemoteMediaPlayer is null, so will not proceed
09-30 17:36:41.684: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] RemoteMediaPlayer::onMetadataUpdated() is reached
09-30 17:36:41.684: D/ccl_VideoCastManager(7630): [v1.10] onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated() reached
```

Here is the Chromecast logs, but it seems there's nothing until I disconnect it.. It's very weird.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined
 [  0.280s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 player.html:1
Connecting to a non-secure WebSocket server from a secure origin is deprecated. player.html:1
 [  0.363s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc cast_receiver.js:18
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined
cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
undefined
 [ 17.665s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"reason\":\"closed_by_peer\",\"senderId\":\"35:com.MY_APP.AndroidApp-12\",\"type\":\"senderdisconnected\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"} cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.676s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.682s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching sender disconnected event [35:com.MY_APP.AndroidApp-12] Reason: requested_by_sender cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.688s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.player.message, 35:com.MY_APP.AndroidApp-12] cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.693s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 35:com.MY_APP.AndroidApp-12] cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.704s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Disposed CastMessageBus[urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system] cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.710s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Disposed CastMessageBus[urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.player.message] cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.716s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Disposed CastMessageBus[urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media] cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 17.729s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Disposed CastReceiverManager cast_receiver.js:18
```

But I have no idea what causes this problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to provide (1) more log from the android side and (2) the console log from your cast device. Without those, it is very difficult to see what is happening. In addition, update to CCL 1.10, if you can. Finally, is onApplicationConnected called at all?

Comment: I updated CCL and onApplicationConnected is called yes.
What do you mean by the console log from my cast device ?

Comment: You need to collect logs from your receiver, see Debugging section here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver. Also, please add more of the log from the Android side; I am interested to see what happens after the part that you show; that is not enough for troubleshooting

Comment: I'm trying to get the Chromecast logs. If I understood your link, I can access it here : http://IP_ADRESS_OF_MY_CHROMECAST:9222 on Google Chrome.
But I'm doing it http://192.168.1.17:9222/ which is its address and I have  "This webpage is not available".
My device is well registered and I'm on the right wifi..

Comment: Ok I could get it working by checking "Send this Chromecast's serial number to google when checking for updated" and rebooting it.
I'll put my logs in the question.

Comment: Where is your getVideoCastManager() defined? Is it in the same activity?

Comment: No it's a singleton in my Application, is it correct this way ? But it's using the same activity as the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I simply needed to add a call to incrementUiCounter in the onResume while setting the videoCastConsumer.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // CHROMECAST
    mVideoCastManager = MyApplication.getVideoCastManager(this);
    mVideoCastManager.addVideoCastConsumer(mVideoCastConsumer);
    mVideoCastManager.incrementUiCounter();
...
```